# Get file from whatsapp share file from uri

Tags: java, android, uri

I Need help to retrieve or get content of file from whatsapp.

Here are my codes and values when i read it:

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); // return text
receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT) // return file name
receivedIntent.getScheme() // null
receivedIntent.getData() // null
receivedIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); // return array of URI
```

my best try is found URI and try to read the content but failed. notes: this file is .txt file (if i send to email, it become  on body with .txt attached.

the problem is my URI form is like this:

```
content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/export_chat/628133xxxx@s.whatsapp.net/829xx-8xxx-4axx-91xx-48d6b33dxxxx
* i trim the content because not sure if it is private code or not
```

I have tried to convert it's URI with code i found here to get file:// format but I still did not get the file or its content because the function returns null

```
public static String getUriPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            System.out.println("getPath() uri: " + uri.toString());
            System.out.println("getPath() uri authority: " + uri.getAuthority());
            System.out.println("getPath() uri path: " + uri.getPath());

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                System.out.println("getPath() docId: " + docId + ", split: " + split.length + ", type: " + type);

                // This is for checking Main Memory
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    if (split.length > 1) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1] + "/";
                    } else {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                    }
                    // This is for checking SD Card
                } else {
                    return "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

am i in correct way or i should use another method to read this `.txt` file?

Comment: *my best try is found URI and try to read the content but failed* How you do this? ... basically ... there is no path ... you have to read content directly using URI ... asked multiple times ... **99% of `getUriPath` implementation is bad** There is only one way 1. create file 2. copy content 3. get the path to created file

Comment: "i should use another method to read this .txt file?" -- pass the `Uri` to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. Read in the contents of the stream. And you're done.

Comment: actually i only need the content. the problem is i can't get it. what in my mind now is to get the content i should get the file first. if you say copy content, can you help me how to read that content?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Commonsware, i try use ContentResolver and InputStream and get what i want.

```
ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
try {
    InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uris.get(0));
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {
        total.append(line).append('\n');
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i'm not mark this as answer yet waiting for another correction or better code.